# How can I change the background color in the button without FXML? #JAVAFX

Tags: user-interface, javafx, colors, project, scenebuilder

I've been trying to change the color of the window completely for a long time. I am missing the lower section.

Can anyone help me?

This is the code.
I apologize for my beginner knowledge.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing. Code behind links or in images is not appropriate - please [edit] your questions and add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

[image: This a demo]

If You want to do something like this the Thing You can do is Using a CSS file in javaFX FXML project
if its not a javaFX ***FXML*** Project then I'm afraid you must share the source code of your project...